# Refresh picture after change

Tags: image, facebook, jsp, gif

I have a video and I share it at my web page. Code examples of my jsp file:

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.xxx/yyy/images/video/video_06.gif?4"/>
...
<link rel="image_src" type="image/gif" href="http://www.xxx/yyy/images/video/video_06.gif?4" />
....
<div class="video"><img src="/yyy/images/video/video_06.gif?4" width="198" height="158" alt="" /></div>
```

My problem is that: I have changed that image with new one(I didn't change the name of gif file.) However it still doesn't refresh picture at server. My solution was that: the name of gif file is video_06.gif and I added ?4 end of it so it became video_06.gif?4. This works at other images at my web page(usual pictures not for facebook) but maybe I do something wrong or facebook doesn't refresh it.

**PS:** I inspected the gif image with firebug and it's name is still video_06.gif not video_06.gif?4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. There was a problem with caching mechanism and Icould see it at my local, I could not see it at live because Facebook was using the URL of live system.